# Unable to read image features - Python Path Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

I am trying to read image features from a publicly available dataset. The author has provided code for importing the image data (available in the `.b` format). However, when I try to specify path, I keep getting an "invalid syntax" error.

I have tried multiple ways of specifying path, including single quotes, double quotes, shifting the file to the working directory, but the error still persists.

Code provided by author:

```py
import array

def readImageFeatures(path): 
  f = open(path, 'rb') 
   while True: 
    asin = f.read(10) 
    if asin == '': break 
    a = array.array('f') 
    a.fromfile(f, 4096) 
    yield asin, a.tolist()
```

I replaced `path` with `image_features_Baby.b` after shifting the `.b` file to the working directory.

Error Message :

```
File "<ipython-input-11-64c836f0cfe3>", line 1 <br>
def readImageFeatures('image_features_Baby.b'): <br>
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax <br>
```

Comment: Since you are trying to work with some Python code you will have to learn a little bit of Python; there are countless good introductions out there.  The code you pasted *defines* a function.  To *call* a function, after it has been defined, you write (in your case) `readImageFeatures('image_features_Baby.b')` without the `def`.  There's no need to modify the function definition itself to hard-code the path to your file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I followed your instructions and ran the code and was able to run the function. However, I am getting the following error : <generator object readImageFeatures at 0x105e04840>. May I please know how to call a specific object and get its features

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code

```
import array

def readImageFeatures(path): 
    f = open(path, 'rb') 
    while True: 
      asin = f.read(10) 
      if asin == '': 
          break 
      a = array.array('f') 
      a.fromfile(f, 4096) 
      yield asin, a.tolist() 

readImageFeatures('image_features_Baby.b')
```

and it worked fine. The only thing i did was clean up the tabs/spaces. That may be your issue. I also put your break on a new line but that shouldn't be your error.

I did have to fix these lines though:

```
f = open(path, 'rb') 
 while True:
```

to

```
f = open(path, 'rb') 
while True:
```

for an indent issue. Also if you are trying to do:

```
import array

def readImageFeatures('some_file_here.txt'): 
   f = open(path, 'rb') 
   while True: 
    asin = f.read(10) 
    if asin == '': break 
    a = array.array('f') 
    a.fromfile(f, 4096) 
    yield asin, a.tolist()
```

than read the comment pinned to the question about the difference between a call and defining the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I followed your instructions and ran the code and was able to run the function. However, I am getting the following error : 
<generator object readImageFeatures at 0x105e04840>. May I please know how to call a specific object and get its features.

Comment: That's not an error.  This function returns a [generator object](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).  You must iterate over it (e.g. using a *for* loop) and it will return whatever this code is supposed to do for each item in the dataset.

Comment: ```yield asin.value_you_want``` or ```[i for i in asin] ``` something like one of these, but i would need to see your code to know exactly what to do.